# Node.js HEAD request returns HPE_INVALID_CONTENT_LENGTH error

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, httprequest, content-length

Using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module I'm getting the following error on HEAD requests to some shortened, 301-redirecting URLs:

```
{ [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 123, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONTENT_LENGTH' }
```

For example, I get this on http://cnb.cx/1vtyQyv. Very easy to reproduce (node v0.10.29, request v2.36.0):

```
var request = require('request');
request({ url:'http://cnb.cx/1vtyQyv', method: 'HEAD' }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(err, res);
});
```

Here is the result of `curl` HEAD request on this URL:

```
$ curl -I http://cnb.cx/1vtyQyv
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 18:16:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private; max-age=90
Content-Length: 124
Location: http://www.cnbc.com/id/101793181
Mime-Version: 1.0
Set-Cookie: _bit=53b44c65-00194-0369a-281cf10a;domain=.cnb.cx;expires=Mon Dec 29 18:16:05 2014;path=/; HttpOnly
```

The content length on the body is in fact 124, as can be verified with `curl http://cnb.cx/1vtyQyv | wc -c`

The error is thrown from within Node.js's core http parser (https://github.com/mattn/http-server/blob/master/http_parser.c), however, strangely, `request` is able to follow this 301 redirect and successfully returns contents of the target page (http://www.cnbc.com/id/101793181) with no error when doing a GET request, which suggests that the error isn't necessary:

```
var request = require('request');
request({ url:'http://cnb.cx/1vtyQyv', method: 'GET' }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(err, res);
});
```

---

This is an issue using [node-unshortener](https://github.com/Swizec/node-unshortener) which makes repeated HEAD requests until it finds the full URL.

Comment: The request module has finally been deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me with plain node v0.10.29:

```
var http = require('http');

http.request({
  host: 'cnb.cx',
  path: '/1vtyQyv',
  method: 'HEAD'
}, function(res) {
  console.dir(res);
  res.resume();
}).end();
```

The error is reproduced with `request` v2.36.0 though. You might want to [file an issue](https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/new) about it.

**UPDATE:** The error is reproduced with plain node, the problem is not the shortened URL, but the redirected URL that causes the problem:

```
http.request({
  host: 'www.cnbc.com',
  path: '/id/101793181',
  method: 'HEAD'
}, function(res) {
  console.dir(res.statusCode);
  console.dir(res.headers);
}).end();

// results in:
//
// events.js:72
//         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
//               ^
// Error: Parse Error
//     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1583:20)
//     at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

**UPDATE #2:**
It turns out that the redirected URL is returning `Content-Length: -1`, which is causing the error. `curl -I http://www.cnbc.com/id/101793181` shows:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 22:23:49 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: User-Agent
Via: 1.1 aicache6
Content-Length: -1
X-Aicache-OS: 10.10.1.25:80
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: max=20`

Comment: Thanks, never used bare `http.request` before but I think that makes it pretty clear it's a bug with `request` - I'll file an issue.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice you're the same person who responded on GitHub. Anyway, yep, you are totally correct, sorry for the false alarm. I've seen a bunch of sites do this now. As a result, for the purposes of unshortening shortened URLs, we must switch to GET: https://github.com/Swizec/node-unshortener/pull/19/files